# JSF 2.0: Why do I got this Inject managed bean Exception

Tags: java, exception, jsf-2, scope

I have the following 2 ManagedBean:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class MakeReservation {
    ...
    @ManagedProperty(value="#{cartManagedBean}")
    private CartManagedBean cartSession;
    ...
}

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class CartManagedBean {
    ...
}
```

When I try to navigate to MakeReservation.xhtml, I saw the following exception:

```
SEVERE: JSF will be unable to create managed bean makeReservation when it is requested.  The following problems where found:
     - The scope of the object referenced by expression #{cartManagedBean}, request, is shorter than the referring managed beans (makeReservation) scope of view
```

Obviously, the scope of `cartManagedBean` is `SessionScope`. I have no idea why the Exception claimed that my bean has `RequestScope`. I have tried to Clean, Build and Run the Project several times but it didn't help.

I'd be very grateful if someone could show me where I have done wrong.

Best regards,

James Tran

Comment: What container have you deployed this to? Could the container be attempting to run an older version? Maybe an exploded war?

Comment: I'm using GlassFish 3 if that's what you're asking for.

Comment: Can you show the packages of the annotations you use please.

Comment: @KayKay: OMG! You're my angel man. I imported `javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped` instead of `javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped`. How stupid I am! =D

Comment: You are welcome! I did the same once ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be carreful to import the right package for your `@SessionScoped` annotation.

Comment: Hey how did you arrive at this answer? ^.^

Comment: I have had a similar problem by not importing the right scope annotations. And I asked in the comments ^^